What is this strange count of characters?
Total beginner in C here.
This simple program:
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF) {
        // don't count newlines
        if (getchar() != '\n') {
            nc++;
        }
    }
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
    return 0;
}

It compiles with no warnings (-Wall flag used), but:
❯ ./countchars
hello
world
4D

What is this 4D? I'm expecting this to return 10.
And how should I count all characters except newlines?

Shouldn't it produce 10 though?

yes obviously. I updated the question accordingly.

You're calling getchar() twice per iteration.

You're calling getchar() twice. Each call consumes a character.

The D is just the latter part of ^D which is printed when you press ctrl-D. It's being partially overwritten by the printf output (4).

Not sure where the "D" is coming from.  Perhaps it's part of your EOF indicator (did you enter ctrl-D to end your input?)  The main problem is your loop.  You realize that every time you call getchar(), it consumes a character from the input, right?  So you're checking the odd characters for EOF and the even characters for '\n', and you're only counting the even characters.  That doesn't make much sense.  When you read a character, save it in an int.  Then check it for both EOF and '\n'.  Then you'll get 10 for your sample input.

You could have tested this without typing a manual ^D to signal EOF: (echo hello; echo world) | countchars

@tchrist perhaps an unfair assumption, but I assume someone who is just starting C is unlikely to have a firm grasp of piping/redirection/bash.

@TomKarzes, I don't understand this: So you're checking the odd characters for EOF and the even characters for '\n', and you're only counting the even characters.  Why are you saying that getchar() only checks odd characters?

Your  getchar() in the while checks for the first character, the getchar() in if checks for the second character, then getchar() in the while checks for the third character, and so on. That's what odd and even mean.

@thiebo getchar() doesn't check anything.  You are the one doing the checking.  One more time:  Every time you call getchar(), it consumes a new character from your input.  So if your string starts with abc, the first call in the loop reads a and checks it against EOF.  The second call in the loop (in the same loop iteration) reads b and checks it against '\n'.  You then increment your counter.  So you read both a and b in the first loop iteration.  And you counted it as 1.  The code you wrote makes no sense.

@thiebo they're explaining the behavior of the (buggy) loop above, not necessarily what you're trying to achieve. You have two calls that alternate back and forth, which basically splits the sequence "0 1 2 3 4 5 ..." into sequences of "0 2 4..." and "1 3 5..." respectively for each call.

got it...

    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF ) {
        if (c != '\n') {
            nc++;
        }
    }


A reminder that getchar() returns an int, and that EOF is a int (typically -1)... so c needs to be of type int

yes absolutely. man 3 getchar is very clear about that.
